# Is there a way to write to a qTableWidget more than once?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5

I am trying to create a qTableWidget in PyQt5 that will allow me to make a selection with a checkbox that filters a Pandas DataFrame and then show that data in the GUI.

I can get it to run the code the first time, and it presents the data just as I would expect.
When you try and refresh it however it won't load the new data into the qTableWidget.
There isn't any error messages, and if you print the DataFrame it is loading the new data as I would expect, it just isn't showing up in the GUI.

I've searched for similar issues on here, but can't find anyone having the same problems I am getting.

I need it to refresh the table in the same GUI as in my real data, the DataFrame is generated from an API call which when selecting a new group will pull the most recent data and could be ran an indefinite number of times.

Here is what I've got up to, I've tried to add comments to explain as much as I can do

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import pandas as pd

class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, tab2_df, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        tab2_df = tab2_df
        nRows = len(tab2_df.index)
        nColumns = len(tab2_df.columns)
        self.setRowCount(nRows)
        self.setColumnCount(nColumns)

        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                x = "{}".format(tab2_df.iloc[i, j])
                self.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(x))
        print(tab2_df) #validating that the new df is received

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Reporting Test"
        self.left = 400
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 1300
        self.height = 700
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        #initialize window with tabs
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget() #Group select Tab
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget() #DataFrame Tab

        # Name and add first Tab to Layout
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Group Select")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Sample DataFrame for demonstation
        self.tab1.df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]})

        # Filter dataframe into a list to show as checkboxes
        self.tab1.group = self.tab1.df[["Name"]]
        self.tab1.groupList = self.tab1.group['Name'].tolist()
        self.tab1.listLabel = ["",] * len(self.tab1.groupList)
        self.tab1.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.grid)

        # Populate the checkboxes with the list
        for i, v in enumerate(self.tab1.groupList):
            self.tab1.groupList[i] = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(v)
            self.tab1.listLabel[i] = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.tab1.grid.addWidget(self.tab1.groupList[i], i, 0)

        # Add the checkboxes into the tab
        self.tab1.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select Group")
        self.tab1.button.clicked.connect(self.checkboxChanged)
        self.tab1.labelResult = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab1.grid.addWidget(self.tab1.button,     i+1, 0, 1,2)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.grid)

    def checkboxChanged(self):
        # Clear the previous tab
        self.tabs.clear()
        # Add a new tab for the loaded data
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Loaded Data")

        # Match the ticked checkbox to the DataFrame and filter to a new DataFrame
        self.tab1.labelResult.setText("")
        for i, v in enumerate(self.tab1.groupList):
            self.tab1.listLabel[i].setText("True" if v.checkState() else "False")
            self.tab1.labelResult.setText("{}, {}".format(self.tab1.labelResult.text(),
                                                     self.tab1.listLabel[i].text()))

        self.tab1.groupList2 = self.tab1.group['Name'].tolist()

        checked2 = str(self.tab1.labelResult.text()).split(',')
        result = list(filter(None, checked2))
        checked_list = {"Name":self.tab1.groupList2, "checked":result}
        checked_list_df = pd.DataFrame(checked_list)
        checked_list_filtered_df = checked_list_df[checked_list_df.checked.str.contains("true", case=False)]
        self.tab1.filteredGroup_df = checked_list_filtered_df
        group_select_df = pd.merge(self.tab1.group, self.tab1.filteredGroup_df, on="Name", how="inner")
        group_select_list = group_select_df["Name"].tolist()
        tab2_df = self.tab1.df[self.tab1.df["Name"].isin(group_select_list)]

        # Populate the filtered DataFrame onto a TableWidget and populate this into the tab
        self.tab2.tableWidget = TableWidget(tab2_df, self)

        # Set headings and style for TableWidget
        self.tab2.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Name", "Age"))
        stylesheet3 = "::section{font: bold 18px}"
        self.tab2.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(stylesheet3)
        # Add button to refresh the data with a new group filter
        self.tab2.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Refresh", self.tab2)
        self.tab2.button.clicked.connect(self.refresh_button)
        self.tab2.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.tab2.tableWidget)
        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.tab2.button)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2.layout)

        # Refresh button that will clear the previous TableWidget and load the Group Select Tab to generate new data
    def refresh_button(self):
        # Clear the previous tab
        self.tabs.clear()
        # Clear the TableWidget
        self.tab2.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        # Load the Group Select Tab to select the new group
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Group Select")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm sure a lot of this could be done much more elegantly and I'm trying to learn as I go, but I just can't figure this bit out.

Comment: What is the point of using a QTabWidget if you are continuously adding and removing tabs when switching from one to another? If you only want one tab to be accessible at the time you could consider using a QStackedWidget instead.

Comment: It's just in this example where only one widget it shown. In my working example I've got 4 of this type of dataframe being shown for different information.

Comment: Do you mean that you have four tabs with different information and for each tab you want to switch between a "select" and a "loaded data" view?

Comment: @Heike That's right.
4 different tabs with different information and a refresh button to change the "filter" which will show different information in those tabs.

I've been planning on having all 4 tabs loaded at the same time, but as I read your comment I realise that you can't read 4 tabs at the same time, so how they load doesn't matter as long as there is buttons to swap tabs, which is the easy bit.

I've not looked at a QStackedWidget yet, so I'll do some research on that and see if it will work for my needs.